# Saving data with concurrency, preventing duplicate IDs

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, concurrency, savechanges

I am working on a project that saves invoices.

I have one table for the `INVOICE` and another one of the `INVOICE_PRODUCTS`. The `ID`s of both tables are calculated (`last value + 1`) and in the `INVOICE` table I also have the `DOCUMENT_NUMBER` that is also calculated (`last document number + 1`).

My problem is when more than one user saves an invoice at the same time. Both of them have the same ID and the same document number.

What is the best way of saving this without having the same ID and document number on both saves? Is there any way of "blocking" one save and when it is finished, start the new one?

Edited:

dymanoid: the IDs are generated in code:

```
last = AllCustomerInvoices()
    .Where(t => t.CUSTOMER_INVOICE_ID.ToString().StartsWith(node))
    .Select(t => t.CUSTOMER_INVOICE_ID)
    .ToList()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Max()
    .ToString();

return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(last) ?
    int.Parse(string.Concat(node, int.Parse(last.Substring(node.Length)))) :
    int.Parse(string.Concat(node, ("0")));
```

mjwills: I do not use IDENTITY columns, because the ID is composed by the nodeID (each store as a different nodeID), but even i had a identity column, the problem maintain on the document_number.

Comment: There's not enough context information in your question. How do you generate IDs? Database (calculated column)? Code on client side? Code on server side? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't using IDENTITY columns? Have you added `UNIQUE` indexes to the table to ensure that duplicates can't occur?

Answer (score -1):

you can use transactions in C# to solve this problem.
You can check here how to use transactions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566(v=vs.110).aspx